# Channel error in SSH

Tags: mongodb, ssh

I want to port locally a remote server over SSH to sync my Mongodb locally and remotely as described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619598/sync-mongodb-via-ssh).

I run:

```
ssh -L27018:localhost:27017 REMOTE_SERVER_HERE
```

However when I type that command locally in a different terminal to get access:

```
$ mongo --port 27018
```

I get:

```
[REMOTE_CONSOLE]\> debug1: Connection to port 27018 forwarding to localhost port 27017 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 27018 for localhost port 27017, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 55428, nchannels 3
```

If I run the same command in the ssh connected terminal I get:

```
[REMOTE_CONSOLE]\> mongo --port 27018
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
url can't have host or port if you specify them individually
```

Does it mean that I am behind a firewall, does the remote administrator has limited this access or something else?

If so how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logical error... The remote server was operating in `127.4.198.2:27017` and not `localhost:27017`.

Comment: see an explanation on superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/346971/ssh-tunnel-connection-refused