# Copy mongo DB from one host to another

Tags: mongodb, database

I am using the following command to copy the `mongoDB` from my live sefver to local server

```
{ copydb: 1,
  fromhost: my-live-ip,
  tohost: 127.0.0.1,
  fromdb: liveDB,
  todb: test_db,
  slaveOk: <bool>,
}
```

But it gives me the following error

```
Error: Line 2: Unexpected token :
```

I am using `Robomongo` UI for this purpose and I am connected to both my live and local mongo DBs

Comment: That isn't even valid JSON, do you actually send those without quotes (`my-live-ip`), and with `<bool>` instead of `true` or `false`?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619598/sync-mongodb-via-ssh/16620593#16620593

Comment: @mnemosyn tried with quotes and `true` or `false`, still the same

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways, as a documentation shows:

- Run copydb in the admin database of the destination server with the
  following syntax:

  ```
  { copydb: 1,
    fromhost: <hostname>,
    fromdb: <database>,
    todb: <database>,
    slaveOk: <bool>,
    username: <username>,
    nonce: <nonce>,
    key: <key> }
  ```
- Copy from remote server with authtentication:

If copying from a remote server and the remote server has authentication enabled, then you must include a **username**, **nonce**, and **key**.

Here is the link: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/copydb/

Its seems you forget the authentication info in copybd command