# How to enable password authentication for remote connection and disable it for local for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

How do I enable user:password authentication for remote connections and disable it for everything that comes from localhost? I have prod running locally and I really don't want to enable any user or password authentication but I want to be able to connect to my DB remotely to manage data on prod.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I enable user:password authentication for remote connections and disable it for everything that comes from localhost?

MongoDB does not support such an arrangement.

If you enable authentication in your deployment, all connections must authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

You have two things to do

**1**- **Allow remote connection to you server by setting a firewall rule.**

For instance, if you are using Linux, this could be done with

```
sudo ufw allow from REMOTE_MACHINE_IP_HERE to any port 27017
```

Don't forget to reload firewall after that

**2**- **Edit mongod.conf to set the IP of the interface you want to allow connection on.**

This would mean you should not allow localhot or 127.0.0.1 on this configuration

Inside mongo.conf, do this

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: mongodb_server_ip_here
```

Restart mongodb server and you're good to go

Answer (score 0):

1. In version >= 3.6 you can add additional restrictions from inside the mongodb instance per user as follow:

   use admin

   db.createUser(
   {
   user: "restricted",
   pwd: "password",
   roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "reporting" } ],
   authenticationRestrictions: [ {
   clientSource: ["40.0.0.0","12.0.0.0"],
   serverAddress: ["120.0.0.0"]
   } ]
   }
   )
2. Additionally it is highly recommended beside the authentication , authorisation and layer 3 firewall restrictions  to enable transport encryption to prevent possible attempts of traffic sniffing ...

But from what I see in your question , if you want to access remotely without user/passwords you may just create ssh tunnel and reditect the local server mongo port to be accessed remotely in the client machine and also define firewall rule so the local server port to not be accessed from the server. This link here seems to answer in details on how you can create ssh tunel to access your mongodb remote server:
[Sync MongoDB Via ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619598/sync-mongodb-via-ssh/16620593#16620593)

You can create the tunnel simply with the command:

```
ssh -L27018:CLIENT1:27017 SERVER1
```

And access to the mongodb server locally from the CLIENT as follow:

```
mongo --port 27018
```